# How to get list of admin users from projects in sonarqube, using API?

Tags: sonarqube

How to get projects having admin users or list of them if multiple admin users on them using API?

I tried few links, but not working.

sonarqube version 8.9, I am using.

Comment: I'm also looking for same did you able to find out solution for it? if yes please post your solution it could helps many other visitors to your post. thanks in Advance!